# Is The First Number a Multiple of the Second Number

Tags: java

I am writing a program that asks the user to input two integers a total of ten separate times.

Next the program needs to evaluate whether or not the first integer is a multiple of the second integer.

If the first is a multiple of the second then the program should print out "true," if it is not then it should print out "false."

Here is my code:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         int counter = 0; // Initializes the counter

         System.out.printf("Enter first integer: "); // asks the user for the first integer
         int number1 = input.nextInt(); // stores users input for the first integer

         System.out.printf("Enter second integer: "); // asks the user for the second integer
         int number2 = input.nextInt(); // stores the users input for the second integer

         while (counter <= 10) // starts a loop that goes to 10
         {
             if (number1 & number2 == 0) // checks to see if number1 is a multiple of number2
                 System.out.print("true"); // if so then print out "true"
             else
                 System.out.print("false"); // otherwise print out "false"
         }

     } // end class
```

Somewhere along the line my code is breaking. Is there anyone who can help, or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use `%` instead of `&` to check if number1 is a multiple of number2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read two inputs 10 times. And test if `number1` is a multiple of `number2`. Something like

```
public static void main(String str[]) throws IOException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
        System.out.printf("Enter first integer for counter %d: ", counter);
        int number1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("Enter second integer for counter %d: ", counter);
        int number2 = input.nextInt();

        // Since you want to print true if number1 is a multiple of number2.
        System.out.println(number1 % number2 == 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` is the bitwise logical AND function. I'm quite sure that won't do what you want it to do.  Seems like you want the MODULO operator, `%`.

E.g. Use number1 % number2. instead of number1 & number2

```
     while (counter <= 10) // starts a loop that goes to 10
     {
         if (number1 % number2 == 0) // checks to see if number1 is a multiple of number2
         System.out.print("true"); // if so then print out "true"

         else
         System.out.print("false"); // otherwise print out "false"
     }
```

Comment: That is right; however, now I need the program to loop through ten times and print out "true" or "false."